# Convert a string holding a dict into a dataframe to get data out

Tags: python, string

I have a string which contains what appears to be a dictionary but I don't know the process to extract and convert it. I tried to convert it using pandas, json, and stringIO but I still having difficultly.

the string is as follows:

```
mystr = ' stage:"house",stop:\'st\',players:3, totalplayers:10'
```

`json` doesn't work as double quotes are not being used.

```
pd.read_json("{" + mystr + "}")
```

I tried to use `StringIO`

what is the simplest method convert this string so I can extract out the total number of players?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split on commas for each key/value pair, then on colons for the keys and values.  Strip results.

```
d = {}
for k, v in [pair.split(':') for pair in mystr.strip().split(',')]:
    d[k.strip()] = v.strip()
>>> d
{'stage': '"house"', 'stop': "'st'", 'players': '3', 'totalplayers': '10'}
```